# FMS 4.5 adding vhost administrators doesn't work

Tags: flash-media-server

May be someone can help me.
I am using FMS 4.5.5 on my windows 7 PC.

I was able to add server admin on the FMS 4.5.5 but when I am trying to add a vhost administrator FMS admin console doesn't wan't to allow me in.

When I am trying to ping the server with server admin credentials () it returns

status

`NetConnection.Call.Success`

11/8/2013 10:55:08 AM

But when I am using vhost admin credentials (http://www.host311.com:1111/admin/ping?auser=host311&apswd=password12) which have already been created I am given this error

error

`NetConnection.Connect.Rejected`

Admin user requires valid username and password.

11/8/2013 10:57:26 AM

Application.xml and Vhost.xml have been taken from the ...\Flash Media Server 4.5\conf_defaultRoot__defaultVHost_\

Vhost.xml has been modified accordingly. ( is picking up the right directory)

Users.xml file has been taken from ...\Flash Media Server 4.5\conf\ and appropriate user has been added to the file:

```
    <!-- This tag defines an administrator for the server. -->

    <User name="host311">

        <!-- Password for this vhost administrator. -->

        <Password encrypt="false">password12</Password>

        <!-- This admin can only connect to the server from the specified -->

        <!-- hosts. This is specified as a comma delimited list of        -->

        <!-- hostnames or domain names, and/or (full or partial) IP       -->

        <!-- addresses. For example,                                      -->

        <!-- "foo.yourcompany.com, macromedia.com, 10.60.1.133, 10.60"    -->

        <Allow></Allow>

        <!-- This admin cannot connect to the server from any of the      -->

        <!-- specified hosts. This is specified as a comma delimited list -->

        <!-- of hostnames or domain names, and/or (full or partial) IP    -->

        <!-- addresses. For example,                                      -->

        <!-- "foo.yourcompany.com, macromedia.com, 10.60.1.133, 10.60"    -->

        <Deny></Deny>

        <!-- Specifies the order in which to evaluate the <Allow> and     -->

        <!-- <Deny> tags. This can be "Allow,Deny" or "Deny,Allow". The   -->

        <!-- default is "Deny,Allow" which means that access is allowed   -->

        <!-- unless specified in <Deny> and not specified in <Allow>.     -->

        <Order>Allow,Deny</Order>

    </User>

</UserList>
```

May be there is no more such possibility to add vhost administrators

Please advise.

Thanks in advance.